# Can I use .done(function... to reflect changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, live

I have this working incrementer for echoed rows from a sql database thanks to users from stackoverflow

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on("click", ".button", function() {
var selectedId = $(this).attr('id');
var $id = selectedId;
$.post( "incrementer.php", {
'id':$id,
}).done(function( data ) {
// alert( "Server response: " + data );
window.location.replace("http://refresh_to_reflect_change.com");

});
});
</script>
```

As you can see, I commented out the `"Server response: " + data` line

For one reason it is empty, and another I'm not sure what to do with it.

Can I get data from the server "on the way back" so for example in this case, I incremented a "likes" and I'd like to reflect that change by increasing the displayed number by 1, can this `.done(function...` be used to get data from the server and send it back sequentially after incrementing?

Comment: Yes, it can be used. You just shouldn't do `location.replace()`, but modify the DOM. E.g. `$('#likes').text(data)`

Comment: Thank you I will try this, most likely thisis the solution